# How can I add a full screen popup alert for Google Calendar events on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-11, calendar, microsoft-edge, google-calendar

I'm looking for something that will create a full-screen notification when Google Calendar meetings are about to begin.

I have something similar on Mac (don't have it in front of me to grab the name) but haven't been able to find the equivalent for Windows.

I'm running Microsoft Edge on Windows 11.

Comment: Looking for the same, what as the one you had for mac?

Comment: I don't know about them, but I'm looking for an alternative similar to In Your Face: https://www.inyourface.app Really can't find anything suitable though. :(